# Return JSON File as PartialView

Tags: asp.net, json, model-view-controller

I have an action method which loads the contents of a file to show a schema for an API. The file just contains a big JSON string. If the file extension is .cshtml, I can do something like

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetSchema()
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/JsonData/_Raw.cshtml");
    }
```

But if I rename the extension to .json (so I can easily format it with VS), then try to do

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetSchema()
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/JsonData/_Raw.json");
    }
```

I get the error

```
The partial view '~/Views/JsonData/_Raw.json' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/JsonData/_Raw.json
```

I've tried changing the *Build Action* to *Content* and *Copy to Output Directory* to *Always*, to no avail.

Is it possible to just read the contents pf a JSON file and display it like this, without having to read it with Newtonsoft.JSON, parse it, then spit it back out.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create Partial View with content like this

```
@model string
   
@Html.Raw(Model)
```

2. If you are using .NET core

- Add this Html to your View

```
<div id="myActionContentContainer"></div>
```

- Add this javascript to your View or javascript file

```
$.get('@Url.Action("GetSchema", "YourController")', { /* input parameters if needed*/}, function (data) {
        $("#myActionContentContainer").html(data);
});
```

3. If you re using ASP.NET MVC, you can use solution for .NET core from step 2, or simply use this in your View:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("GetSchema");}
```

4. Your method in Controller should looks like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetTestPartialJson()
{
//json = your json, below json is example
   var json = "{" + $"\"Date\":\"2019-08-01T00:00:00-07:00\",\"TemperatureCelsius\":25,\"Summary\":\"Hot\"" + "}";
            return PartialView("_TestPartialJson", json);
}
```